# Reading a costume binary data file into a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, binary

A pressure scanner outputs a binary data file with the following format

Snip out the user manual  of binary file format:

[image]

I like to create a pandas data frame with all fields in separate columns and the temperature and pressure arrays unpacked in separate columns.

I am not very familiar with reading costume binary files and can use some help to start.

Best regards,
Jan

Comment: could you post your file format in text please?

Comment: other question, its just one record or more records of same type could exist?

Comment: Look at module `struct`

Answer (score 0):

here a solution showing how to do. I am just reading only one record and i have not implemented all columns (its long), just some. You have just to add the missing column.
So i have exploded the Temp and pressure in different column, just read the loop.

Last thing i am using the the library bitstring, that's really simplify the binary read and here i am using the big endian, because the file format is in this format

some readings [bitstring](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/constbitstream.html#bitstring.ConstBitStream.read)

```
import pandas as pd
from  bitstring import ConstBitStream

#creating columns names
columnNames = ['pType', 'pSize', 'fNumber', 'scT', 'unitconv', 'exTrigger']
for i in range(8):
    columnNames.append('Temp' + str(i+1))
for i in range(64):
    columnNames.append('Pressure' + str(i+1))

columnNames.append('fTime_sec');columnNames.append('fTime_nano')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnNames)
print(df)

s = ConstBitStream(filename='e:\\+poub\\test.pdf')

index = 0
#you could do a loop if more records in file
#read file bytes and put in the equivalent column of dataframe
df.at[index, 'pType']=  s.read(4 * 8).intbe      #read 4 bytes int big endian
df.at[index, 'pSize'] = s.read(4 * 8).intbe      #again
df.at[index, 'fNumber'] = s.read(4 * 8).intbe
df.at[index, 'scT'] = s.read(4 * 8).intbe
df.at[index, 'unitconv'] = s.read(4 * 8).intbe
df.at[index, 'exTrigger'] = s.read(4 * 8).uintbe #read uint big endian
#read 8 temp of 4 bytes in floatb be
for i in range(8):   
    df.at[index, 'Temp' + str(i+1)] = s.read(4 * 8).floatbe
#read 64 pressure of 4 bytes in floatbe
for i in range(64):
    df.at[index, 'Pressure' + str(i+1)]= s.read(4 * 8).floatbe
df.at[index, 'fTime_sec'] = s.read(4 * 8).intbe
df.at[index, 'fTime_nano'] = s.read(4 * 8).intbe

print(df)
```

Comment: Hi Frenchy, Thanks this helps me a lot. Best regards, Jan

Comment: if the answer is ok dont forget to validate it please

Comment: Validation will take a time the experimental setup in our wind tunnel is just in preparation phase realistic data is not yet available. I will test it with a dummy set of data.

Comment: Validation ok??

Comment: Hi Frenchy, Validation is oké. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: if this answer helps you, please, dont forget to uvpvote/validate the answer !!

Answer (score 0):

The method proposed by Frenchy worked but with the numbers of records we have it performed not fast enough. The final code is a lot faster:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a data type with the binary data format and desired column names
dataType = [
      ('pType', 'i4'),
      ('pSize', 'i4'),
      ('frNumber','i4'),
      ('scType', 'i4'),
      ('frRate', 'f4'),
      ('vStatus', 'i4'),
      ('unitsIndex', 'i4'),
      ('unitConvFactor', 'i4'),
      ('ptpScanStart_sec', 'i4'),
      ('ptpScanStart_nsec', 'i4'),
      ('exTrigger_usec', 'u4')
      ]
# add the 8 temperatures to datatype
for i in range(8):
    dataType.append(('T'+str(i), 'f4'))
# add the 64  pressures to datatype
for i in range(64):
    dataType.append(('P'+str(i), 'f4'))
# append last items to data type
dataType.append(('frTime_sec', 'i4'))
dataType.append(('frTime_nsec', 'i4'))
dataType.append(('exTrigger_sec', 'i4'))
dataType.append(('exTrigger_nsec', 'i4'))    

dt= np.dtype(dataType)

# read data 
pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.fromfile('./data/700hz_180sec.dat', dtype=dt))
```